# JQuery event should change src of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, window, document

The Layout looks like this (more or less):

I have my index-page with two iframes, the left for the navigation and the right for the actuall content. In the html-document for the navigation, I have a little script (JQuery) which animates the buttons when you hover over them / click them. What I need to add of course is that a click on the button actually would change the source of the second iframe.(Content-Frame, id="I2")`

Butt no matter what I am writing, the script breaks and the animations get lost.

I had something like this in mind:

```js
window.document.GetElementById("I2").src = "Content/some_other_html_page.html";
// or:
parent.document.GetElementById("I2").src = "..." ;
```

But it just wont work. The script gets lunched in the html-document of the first iframe. Can somebody helps me? I really sat there yesterday evening for like 2 hours just searching for results in the internet and pressing F5 on my edited webpage.

Comment: *As far as you can avoid using iframe*. You can achieve the results you want easily removing the iframes and using two divs instead.

Comment: Use divs and then use this to set their content - http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: `getElementById()`, JavaScript is case-sensitive language.

Comment: Hi, 
I realy don't get what you mean with using divs instead of iframes. Can I use divs and load a .html-Doc into them?

@ getElementById() was a typo in the topic, sorry. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jQuery already included, you can use:

```
$("#I2", window.parent.document).attr("src", "Content/some_other_html_page.html");
```

You have to use the context `window.parent.document` in order to select the iframe from within the other navigation iframe.

Comment: Does that work even if the Script gets launched in an other document? I have to go now but will try the results as soon as possible. Thanks four you help @ all. :)

(new record for fastest response. :D )

Comment: Sorry, I missed that documents are different. Corrected my answer. ;-)

Comment: Do I have to reload the iframe-content? it does not realy works like this but at least, it does proceed with the rest of the script. :) (I already faild with this)

Comment: No, reloading should not be required actually. Here is an example how to change properties of the parent page from inside an iframe: http://www.css-arts.com/iframe_test/iframe_test.html You just have to replace the line where I change the height of the iframe by the code above. If you cannot figure it out, please show us some code.

Comment: I found the problem and this is maybe interesting for other people in the future. The problem was actually chrome, it blocked my scripts somehow because they are stored localy. It worked with firefox, IE however, is the problematic child like everytime. (not even my JQuery Animations work with IE)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

for changing the URL of an iframe You can do it like this

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Chnageurl" onclick="changeurl()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeurl(e) {
            $('#iframe').attr('src', 'someother url');
            return false;
        }

</script>
```